# What does the "bad indentation of mapping entry" error mean in Swagger Editor?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm getting the "bad indentation of mapping entry" error in the Swagger Editor for the OpenAPI definition below. Can anyone tell what's wrong with the code below?

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: List all applicable errors for API
          headers:
            x-request-received-at:
              type: string
              description: A datetime stamp of when the request was received
            x-response-sent-at:
              type: string
              description: A datetime stamp of when the response was sent
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
        default:
          description: An unexpected error occurred
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
   '/funeral/{contractReference}/agreement':
     get:
        summary: Get the funeral policy and debit order mandate agreement for the client to sign
        operationId: 
         - get801FuneralCoverPlanAgreementHtml
         - getAUTHORITYANDMANDATEFORPAYMENTINSTRUCTIONSHTML
        tags:
         - "FuneralCoverService"
         - "InternalAPI"
        parameters:
         - name: contractReference
        in: "path"
        required: true
        type: string
        description: "Unique contract reference linked to the quote and estimate prepared for the client which should be used as input to the agreements."
        maxLength: 80
```

[image: Swagger Editor: bad indentation of mapping entry error]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter attributes are misaligned. All attributes must have the same indentation level.

Wrong:

```
        parameters:
         - name: contractReference
        in: "path"
        required: true
        type: string
        description: "Unique contract reference linked to the quote and estimate prepared for the client which should be used as input to the agreements."
        maxLength: 80
```

Correct:

```yaml
        parameters:
         - name: contractReference
           in: "path"
           required: true
           type: string
           description: "Unique contract reference linked to the quote and estimate prepared for the client which should be used as input to the agreements."
           maxLength: 80
```